# Collection_select with Simple_form for category selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have category names entered into a categories table in my db. I wanted to assign a product to that category via simple_form. I cant get it to pass through and accept the category.

This is my selector..

```
<%= simple_form_for :pack, url: packs_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name,prompt: "Select Category", class: "form-control center" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add product to grid", class: "btn btn-success btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my packs controller

```
def index
  @packs = Pack.includes(:category).group_by { |pack| pack.category.name }
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

My associations are as follows;

Category model: `has_many :packs`

Pack model: `belongs_to :category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SimpleForm` shortcut to do this:

`f.association :category, prompt: "Select Category", input_html: { class: "form-control center" }`

---

Looks like you are using `Bootstrap`, you should use this command to integrate `SimpleForm` and `Bootstrap`: `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`.

After doing this, you don't need to specify something like `form-group, form-control, ....`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on bootstrap! Your solution prompted this error: `Association cannot be used in forms not associated with an object` I have a `category` column in my packs db table, and I have `name` in my categories table that holds the available categories.

Comment: You should use `simple_form_for Pack.new`, `Pack.new` not `:pack`, and you don't need to specify `url`, Rails will do everything for you

Comment: for some reason, it is saying `undefined method category_id' for #<Pack:0x7452cf0>
Did you mean?  category
               category?
               category=
               category_was`

Comment: Do you have column `category_id` in the table `packs`?

Comment: No, it's just category. Do I need to change this?

Comment: You have to change this to `category_id` (integer). This is foreign key

Comment: Okay, there is no more error, but it doesn't seem to create the pack. My categories table that is associated with the pack has `name :string` as its column. Does this need to be changed or is that ok to use?

Comment: `packs.category_id` will be stored `categories.id`, so `categories.name` is unrelated. To create the pack, you have to permit `category_id` in `PacksController`

Comment: I have changed it to this: `@packs = Pack.includes(:category_id).group_by { |pack| pack.category.id }` Yet it doesn't work. Is this not what you meant? I'm kind of a noob at ruby, thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: @Jake You said you wanted to create, but I saw the code from action `index`?

Comment: Ah, your right! I forgot to include `:category_id` in my `.permit()` It creates the pack now!

Answer (score 3):

In simple form, you have to use this.

```
<%= f.input :category, collection: Category.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id,label: "Category", include_blank: false, selected: @pack.category_id %>
```

Comment: It says category_id is an undefined method.

Comment: It still says category_id is an undefined method. Am I missing something in a model or a controller?

Comment: do you have `category_id` in packs table?